# Access to c pointer in python class from python method, cython

Tags: python, c++, integration, cython

In the process of implementing my python integration I faced a problem.
I have class that looks like this:

```
cdef class SomeClass:
    cdef CPPClass* cpp_impl

    def some_method(self):
        self.cpp_impl.cppMethod()
```

And I have cpp class that can return `CPPClass*` value. Smth like this:

```
class Creator
{
public:
    CPPClass* createClass();

}
```

So I'd like to create SomeClass instance like this:

```
cdef class PyCreator:
    cdef Creator* cpp_impl

    def getSomeClass(self):
        o = SomeClass()
        o.cpp_impl = self.cpp_impl.createClass()
        return o
```

But I'm getting error that cython can't convert `CPPClass*` to Python object.
How can I solve my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In `getSomeClass` it needs to know what type `o` is so that the assignment to `cpp_impl` makes sense:

```
def getSomeClass(self):
    cdef SomeClass o = SomeClass() # define the type
    o.cpp_impl = self.cpp_impl.createClass() # I think you missed a "self" here
    return o
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Ye, I edited my answer cause I forgot to use `self` word, but it was not my problem. My problem is that i can't get access to pointer from python method.

Comment: ...which is what the `cdef SomeClass o = ...` should do. It then knows that `o.cpp_impl` is a `CPPClass` pointer, and so should work